# Not working Drag&Drop file from File Roller to Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.10, wayland, file-roller

On Ubuntu 17.10, both gnome and ubuntu gnome, always with Wayland, I am unable to drop files dragged from file roller on nautilus.

It works the other way, dropping files from nautilus to file roller.

I'm not able to drop files anywhere when dragged from file-roller.  The same thing happened when trying other unzippers.

Any solution?  Any idea what unzipper will work?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can't you just use the extract feature?

Comment: @MichaelBay, yes, I'm using the extract feature.  Much much slower than just dragging and dropping.

Comment: Maybe you will find this bug report helpful: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776635

Comment: Continue not working on Ubuntu 18.04, so it's not Wayland the one to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled file-roller, and now it works well.

It failed under ubuntu 17.10 on both wayland and xorg, and on 18.04, so the problem wasn't related to Wayland.